# How to apply pessimistic lock on Criteria query to implement select for update in hibernate?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, locking, hibernate-criteria

Below is query.

```
DetachedCriteria dc= DetachedCriteria.forClass(ADMPregenAWBMaster.class)
                .add(Restrictions.eq("carrCode", awbEntity.getCarrierCode()))
                .add(Restrictions.eq("tenantId", awbEntity.getTenantId()))
                .add(Restrictions.eq("logisticTypeCode", awbEntity.getDeliveryType()))
                .add(Restrictions.eq("paymentType", awbEntity.getPaymentType()))
                .setProjection(Projections.property("pregenAWBId"));


CMPregenAWBSeq pregen= (CMPregenAWBSeq)session.createCriteria(CMPregenAWBSeq.class)
                .add(Subqueries.propertyIn("compsiteKey.pregenMaster", dc))
                .setLockMode(LockMode.UPGRADE_NOWAIT)
                .setMaxResults(1)
                .uniqueResult();
pregen.setUsedFlag("Y");
session.update(pregen);
```

When I select the table row based on criteria lock should be applied and any other thread should not be able to read the query until the table row is updated. I am not sure if the above code works as expected.

Any help will be much appreciated.